# Low audio output from DJ controller

Tags: sound, dj, mixing, mixer

Not sure if this is the right place to post this.. but please point me in the right direction if not.

I have a Denon DN-MC6000 controller, i usually mix on my PA system. However i would like to be able to mix at night without waking the neighbors.

I bought a RCA to female jack cable which allows me to output the master sound through a pair of earbuds, i can then stick my headphones over the top to monitor the next track.

The problem is that the volume of the sound coming through the ear buds is very quiet, if i turn up the gains on the controller, it just red lines and starts clipping.

Do i need some sort of mini amplifier to run through? or some sort of amplified ear buds? or can i just run it through my PA system amp (way too large for ear buds though)

Comment: You might need a small [headphone amp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headphone_amplifier). Have you tried the other outputs? PA might work also as a kind of headphone amp if you are careful.

Comment: Yea i think that would be the best option. I have just tried to link my headphones up using my PA amp, but the audio out is 2x 6.5mm jacks. Unless i could get some converter of some sort?

Comment: Yeah they make Y-adapters- you want [dual 6.5mm mono > stereo 3.5mm female](http://cdn3.volusion.com/evjgo.knynx/v/vspfiles/photos/AUDIO_006-2.jpg)

Comment: I just had a run out to maplins and bought one, fingers crossed it will work. Thanks for the advice! If you post as an answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved from comments:

The best way to do this would be to use a [headphone amp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headphone_amplifier). Usually the RCA outputs from DJ gear isn't strong enough to power headphones, so you need something in between to go from line level to headphone level. They do make some great portable headphone amps that are about the size of a pack of cigarettes.

You also mentioned you have a PA system, so you can use that if you don't want to spend the money on a headphone amp (though it might not sound as good, and you have to be more careful because the gear isn't designed for this purpose unless the PA has a headphone out). Since it has 6.5mm outputs, you are going to want a  [dual 6.5mm mono > stereo 3.5mm female](http://cdn3.volusion.com/evjgo.knynx/v/vspfiles/photos/AUDIO_006-2.jpg) Y-adapter. Hook that to the outputs then you can plug your earbuds into the female end. Just be careful with the gain and output levels to make sure you don't overpower the earbuds.

Even with the right adapter you might still run into the same problem- those PA outputs are line level and your headphones might need a stronger signal to run them.

Comment: Brilliant, I went and bought an adapter I'm now mixing using my PA amp on a low setting. It works perfect, thanks!